# "error": "invalid_client" while using Django OAuth toolkit

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

I was following the steps mentioned in the [documentation](https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/stable/rest-framework/getting_started.html#step-3-register-an-application) for django rest framework.
I'm not able to proceed from step 4.
As mentioned in the documentation,

```
curl -X POST -d "grant_type=password&username=<user_name>&password=<password>" -u"<client_id>:<client_secret>" http://localhost:8000/o/token/
```

I have changed the above variables with my values.

```
curl -X POST -d "grant_type=password&username=admin&password=admin123" -u "5hKeHNtF3EKy3uCpJqaAe3mU2bGZTgJhsKKxIuAQ:pbkdf2_sha256$390000$VFcCOjIZkBFObellddDgKA$DXovC1UiuxRQ0KN/lARIdQmXcj8dnoJofkznmkkqsZY=" http://localhost:8000/o/token/
```

I tried to import the curl on postman and Im getting this error
[image]

Then I tried running the curl on Insomnia testing tool, and I got the request configured as in the screenshot.
[image][image]

Then I click send and I got an error
[image]

SO i changed 'Content-Type' to 'Form URL Encoded'
[image]

Now I'm geting an error

```
{
"error": "invalid_client"
}
```

I tried running the curl in shell also, and I'm getting an invalid syntax error
[image]

I'm stuck with this and don't know how to proceed with this. Please lend me a hand.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was using the hashed value for **client_secret** instead of the actual value.

How to get actual **client_secret** actual value?

Answer:
While creating new application, copy the **Client secret** before saving
the values
[image]

https://github.com/jazzband/django-oauth-toolkit/issues/1193